# Plumbing plan for freestanding tub

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, drain-waste-vent, cleanout

remodeling my master bath (3rd floor), replacing the old acrylic shower/tub unit with a clawfoot tub. Want to make sure I'm doing the plumbing correctly.

[image: This is a picture of the actual space with overlay of the plan.]

Tub outline (roughly) in black. Plumbing pipes in white, yellow for cleanout. Joists in blue.

The orange 8" is to do with hole boring rules for I-beam joists. A 3" bore hole requires 8" distance from the exterior wall.

Does this look to code?

Help appreciated!